# How to get a value inside of a JSON that is inside a column in a table in Oracle sql?

Tags: sql, oracle

Suppose that I have a table named `agents_timesheet` that having a structure like this:

```
 ID | name |                   health_check_record                  | date        | clock_in | clock_out  
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 1  | AAA  | {"mental":{"stress":"no", "depression":"no"},          | 6-Dec-2021  | 08:25:07 |
    |      |  "physical":{"other_symptoms":"headache", "flu":"no"}} |             |          |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 2  | BBB  | {"mental":{"stress":"no", "depression":"no"},          | 6-Dec-2021  | 08:26:12 |
    |      |  "physical":{"other_symptoms":"no", "flu":"yes"}}      |             |          |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 3  | CCC  | {"mental":{"stress":"no", "depression":"severe"},      | 6-Dec-2021  | 08:27:12 |
    |      |  "physical":{"other_symptoms":"cancer", "flu":"yes"}}  |             |          |
```

Now I need to get all agents having flu at the day. As for getting the `flu` from a single JSON in Oracle SQL, I can already get it by this SQL statement:

```
SELECT * FROM JSON_TABLE(
   '{"mental":{"stress":"no", "depression":"no"}, "physical":{"fever":"no", "flu":"yes"}}', '$'
   COLUMNS (fever VARCHAR(2) PATH '$.physical.flu')
);
```

As for getting the values from the column `health_check_record`, I can get it by utilizing the `SELECT` statement.

But How to get the values of `flu` in the JSON in the `health_check_record` of that table?

**Additional question**

Based on the table, how can I retrieve full list of `other_symptoms`, then it will get me this kind of output:

```
 ID | name |  other_symptoms
-------------------------------
 1  | AAA  | headache
 2  | BBB  | no
 3  | CCC  | cancer
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to get the values of flu in the JSON in the health_check_record of that table?

From Oracle 12, to get the values you can use `JSON_TABLE` with a correlated `CROSS JOIN` to the table:

```sql
SELECT a.id,
       a.name,
       j.*,
       a."DATE",
       a.clock_in,
       a.clock_out
FROM   agents_timesheet a
       CROSS JOIN JSON_TABLE(
         a.health_check_record,
         '$'
         COLUMNS (
           mental_stress     VARCHAR2(3) PATH '$.mental.stress',
           mental_depression VARCHAR2(3) PATH '$.mental.depression',
           physical_fever    VARCHAR2(3) PATH '$.physical.fever',
           physical_flu      VARCHAR2(3) PATH '$.physical.flu'
         )
       ) j
WHERE  physical_flu = 'yes';
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=2052b5f19527f3789034c673e14e46a5)*

Answer (score 2):

You can use JSON_EXISTS() function.

```
SELECT *
  FROM agents_timesheet 
 WHERE JSON_EXISTS(health_check_record, '$.physical.flu == "yes"');
```

There is also "plain old way" without JSON parsing only treting column like a standard VARCHAR one. This way will not work in 100% of cases, but if you have the data in the same way like you described it might be sufficient.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM agents_timesheet 
 WHERE health_check_record LIKE '%"flu":"yes"%';
```

Comment: The "plain old way" will fail if there are spaces around the `:` or may give unexpected results if the `"flu"` key can appear in multiple objects within the JSON and you want a specific path.

Comment: @MT0 sure, the "plain old way" is not 100% bulletproof. It depends on how data is formated and also how other values are. I was considering data is the same like in the question and for this case it will work.

Comment: Important to note this JSON syntax available in 12c and higher...

Comment: Could you give me detailed explanation about what `jscol` is, how it works, and why use it?

Comment: @DhanaD. sorry, I meant `health_check_record`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use "dot notation" to access data from a JSON column. Like this:

```
select "DATE", id, name
from   agents_timesheet t
where  t.health_check_record.physical.flu = 'yes'
;


DATE          ID  NAME
-----------  ---  ----
06-DEC-2021    2  BBB
```

Note that this approach requires that you use an alias for the table name (so you can use it in accessing the JSON data).

For testing I used the data posted by MT0 on dbfiddle. I am not a big fan of double-quoted column names; use something else for `"DATE"`, such as `dt` or `date_`.